# Why can't my user access data from a has-many relationship in this database-first context?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm having some trouble accessing data is a one-to-many relationship where a user has many books. This is a database first scenario (which is why I ran the scaffolding command).

Here is how I'm trying to access the data:

```
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
    var user = db.User.First(u => u.UserId == 1);
    var firstBook = user.Book.First(); // error: Sequence contains no elements
}
```

I generated my context and models with the command:

```
dnx ef dbcontext scaffold "ConnectionString" EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer --outputDir DatabaseModels
```

In the context, the only reference to this relationship is on the `Book`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Book>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasOne(d => d.UserIdNavigation).WithMany(p => p.Book).HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

});
```

And the relevant portions of both `Book` and `User`:

Book:

```
public virtual User UserIdNavigation { get; set; }
```

User:

```
public virtual ICollection<Book> Book { get; set; }
```

---

Any ideas what the problem could be?

If I load up the Book first, and inspect it's user relationship, then the `user.Book.First()` line works.

For example:

```
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
    var user = db.User.First(u => u.UserId == 1);
    var userFromBook = db.Book.Last().UserIdNavigation;
    var firstBook = user.Book.First(); // now this succeeds
}
```

Obviously, it's not ideal to always have to lookup the records directly from the context that you want to access through a relationship.

Comment: Try `db.User.First(...).Include(u => u.Book)`

Comment: Side note... I would call the navigation property `Books` instead of `Book`.

Comment: The scaffold generated all that based on the database tables, I believe, which for some reason were decided to all be singularly named. :-(

Comment: So... you can't just call a relationship have it lazily fetch the data?!? you have to specify all the relationships you might want when you get the user? :-(

Comment: hey, @DStanley, I'm getting an error with that - 'User' does not contain a definition for 'Include'. :-\  Are you sure that is what you're supposed to do with EF7?

Comment: oh, Include goes before the .First()

Comment: @DStanley shouldn't the functionality I want be Lazy-Loading? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx